# React native unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

My App worked perfectly fine the other day and I didn't change anything but as soon as I try to run it on android now it shows this:

[image]

Comment: Did you install any node packages before you go the error? Try deleting and reinstall node_modules `npm install`

Comment: I have tried that already but thanks for the comment